# Unable to Send Keys To Website with Selenium Python on Centos in Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log into a website with Selenium in Python.  My code is below.  I am able to sucessfully find (by_xpath) the username field and print its attributes.  However, I am unable to send_keys to it or interact with it in any way.  Further, I am unable to even select the password field, even though various xpath utilities tell me I am using the right address for the field.

I would like to input my username, password and click submit.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains, keys

import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fgames.espn.go.com%2Fffl%2Fleaguerosters%3FleagueId%3D1111554")
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys("JimH")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys("N0tMyR3@1P@55w0rd")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

You can see in my code that the site that I am trying to access is [this](http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/signin?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fgames.espn.go.com%2Fffl%2Fleaguerosters%3FleagueId%3D1111554).

I have searched this forum extensively for a solution:

- This didn't help because I wasn't sure how to send keys, all this idd was click.  Also it didn't provide descriptive error messages: [Selenium Element not visible exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception)
- When I tried this one I got an exception that the box I was trying to select was outside the scroll window, which was not true: [Unable to select radio button with selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947985/unable-to-select-radio-button-with-selenium-in-python)
- Another post told me to select an frame  which i was unable to do. (select_frame("disneyid-iframe") errored out on me)

The exception that I receive from my code above is pasted here:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ff/PycharmProjects/Test/Test_action_chain.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ff/PycharmProjects/Test/Test_action_chain.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys("JimH")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 328, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 454, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpOFHnLq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9981)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpOFHnLq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12517)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpOFHnLq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpOFHnLq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpOFHnLq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form which you are trying to fill is within an `iframe`. To make selenium work in an `iframe` you need to switch to the specific frame you wish to work in using [`switch_to_frame()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) function. The syntax which you mentioned is incorrect. Try the code given below.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(link)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("disneyid-iframe"))

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys("JimH")
...
```

When you want to get out of the frame, use this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**TIP:** Use [waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#waits) instead of `time.sleep(10)`.

Comment: Jason, your suggestion worked!  Thank you for your prompt and thorough response!  Can you explain briefly how I would know that the elements that I was looking for were on a different frame?

Comment: Use the developer console of the browser to see the element tree of the HTML page. For Chrome, you can follow this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles#inspecting-elements). For Firefox, follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector).